# Python plotly "gantt" chart with times on x-axis, using datetime with plotly

Tags: python, datetime, visualization, plotly

Plotly has the ability to make bar charts with spaces in them, similar to a Gantt chart.  I want to use this capability to create a figure that looks like a Gantt chart, but has a "time x-axis" instead of a "day x-axis".

For example,

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import datetime

trace1 = go.Bar(
    y = ['Task 1', 'Task 1'],
    base = [1, 2.5],
    x = [0.5, 1],
    orientation = 'h' 
)


fig = go.Figure(data=[trace1])
iplot(fig)
```

`base` positions the start of each bar and `x` is the length of each bar

[image: example figure]

However, this only seems to work for decimal numbers. Ideally, I would like the x-axis to be a time axis and say "1:00, 2:00... 24:00" instead of 1, 1.5, etc.

However, when I try this, the results are a little bizarre.

```
trace0 = go.Bar(
    y = ['Task 1', 'Task 1'],
    base = [datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 1, 0),
            datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 2, 30)],
    x = [datetime.time(0, 30),
         datetime.time(1, 0)],
    orientation = 'h' 
)

fig = go.Figure(data=[trace0])
iplot(fig)
```

[image: example of bad plot]

It's not clear to me how plotly is handling the datetime and time objects, I would like there to be two bars that start at 1 am and 2:30 am respectively, with a length of 30 min and 1 hour respectively.

How can I achieve this?